# Video Element Problems with HTML5

Tags: jquery, html5-video

I'm having some problems with using the HTML5 Video tag. I am building a page that needs to work in Safari only (will be running on iPad) and so I am using the video tag. However, the controls won't show or work on any of the videos except the last instance on the page. I do have the videos in different divs some of which are hidden and shown through jQuery commands. Any thoughts why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should post some code or start a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Ok good idea, here's my code. http://jsfiddle.net/t4WQS/4/

Comment: Can you set the video url, so that the script works (or demos what you're talking about)? Hopefully, then we won't have cross-domain issues.

Comment: Did you solve this or make any progress?

Comment: Can you send your code? So that i or someone else can check what's problem with that? You said you want to display video only iPad what if use open it from any other browser or machine?

Comment: not sure if this helps but I read something about having to add unique IDs for each video element..

Comment: try simply having  
    <video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay >  

not controls="controls"